# How do I precompile an Entity Framework Code-First Query?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am encountering some performance problems with my Entity Framework Code-First queries and I believe that precompilation may be the answer. If I were using "normal" Entity Framework, I would simply use the [CompiledQuery.Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.compile.aspx) method to precomiple my queries. But since I have a DbContext and not an ObjectContext, I can't get this to work.

I do realize that DbContext is an [IObjectContextAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.iobjectcontextadapter%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), which gives me access to the ObjectContext, but I cannot find the method that lets me get an IQueryable from my object context that works in my precompiled query. I tried to use [CreateObjectSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382944.aspx), but when EF tried to run the query it complained that it couldn't convert that method into SQL.

**So what is the best way to precompile LINQ queries against a Code-First DbContext?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As from the official announecment:

"No compiled query support from DbContext 
Unfortunately due to some technical limitations in the compiled query functionality we shipped in .NET Framework 4.0 we are unable to support compiled queries via the DbContext API. We realize this is a painful limitation and will work to enable this for the next release. "

[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/02/ef-4-1-is-coming-dbcontext-api-amp-code-first-rtw.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

This will be probably solved in <strike>EFv4.2</strike> EF vNext (currently in the [very first CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx)) by [auto-compiled LINQ queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/30/auto-compiled-linq-queries-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx).

Comment: This means that it will only be available on .NET 4.5? Or will it be released in EF4.3?

Comment: @billy: No. At the moment it is only available with .NET 4.5 but you can use [this](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/10/05/ef-enums-and-spatial-types-on-net-4/) to have it in .NET 4.0.