# Compiled Query no implicit reference conversion to ObjectContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectcontext, compiled-query

I'm creating a delegate to retrieve all album records in the database. I've used this same way in another project, but for some reason I'm getting an error this time.

Have I missed a step? I'm not sure why this error is appearing.

**Code**

```
        public static readonly Func<CodySolutionEntities, IQueryable<Album>> SelectAlbums =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<CodySolutionEntities, IQueryable<Album>>(
            query => from q in query.Albums.Include("Photo")
                     select q);
```

**Error**

Error  1   The type 'CodyData.Diagram.CodySolutionEntities' cannot be used as type `parameter 'TArg0' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile<TArg0,TResult>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TArg0,TResult>>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CodyData.Diagram.CodySolutionEntities' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'. C:\Users\Cody\Documents\CMBS\CodySolution\CodyData\Delegates\PhotoDelegates.cs  13  13  CodyData`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message indicates that `CodySolutionEntities` is not derived from `ObjectContext`, which is a problem because the `CompiledQuery` only works with an `ObjectContext`.  In this case `CodySolutionEntities` must be derived from a `DbContext` object which, at this time, is [the recommended context object to use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx).

The `CompiledQuery` probably worked in the past because, Entity Framework versions prior to 4.1 created an object derived from `ObjectContext` instead of `DbContext` for you to manage your entities.

Like [this](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/entity-framework/entity-framework-5-143875) post explains, if you're able to target .NET 4.5 you can use EF 5, and you won't need the `CompiledQuery` anymore as it will automatically cache compiled LINQ to Entity queries for you.  If not you may want to look into switching back to using an `ObjectContext`, but before doing that make sure your mindset isn't simply [compiled or bust](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/compiled-or-bust.html).

Comment: What would be the equivalent way using `DbContext` to do what I'm trying to do, then?

Comment: That's the problem, you **cannot** use `DbContext` with `CompiledQuery`.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6731102/1289454 .  Could you just stick with a query that isn't compiled? `using(var context = new CodySolutionEntities()){  var albums = context.Albums.Include(a => a.Photos); //... }`

Comment: To answer your question, the equivalent is: public static readonly Func<CodySolutionEntities, IQueryable<Album>> SelectAlbums =
        query => from q in query.Albums.Include("Photo") select q;
But I have no idea if this would be any more efficient than using it inline.