# Entity Framework 6 Compiled LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, caching, compiled-query

I'm trying to improve performance of a web application by caching a query.

```
    public static Func<myEntity, List<HASHDuplicates>, IQueryable<FormResponse>> CompiledDuplicatedResponses =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<myEntity, List<HASHDuplicates>, IQueryable<FormResponse>>(
    (db, hashes) => from r in db.FormResponse
                    from h in db.IndexHASHes
                    from d in hashes
                    where r.id == h.FormResponseID && h.IndexHASHString == d.hash
                    select r);
```

The error I receive is at compile time:

**The type 'myEntity' cannot be used as type parameter 'TArg0' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'myEntity' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext'.**

I'm using EF6

Comment: You need the `ObjectContext` object as the first type parameter of the `Compile` method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok it seems that in EF5 and greater the queries are automatically compiled and there is no need to compile them.
The ObjectContext is not used anymore, and we have now DbContext:
[Compiled Query no implicit reference conversion to ObjectContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287458/compiled-query-no-implicit-reference-conversion-to-objectcontext)

Another interesting post on Compiled Query:
http://blog.codinghorror.com/compiled-or-bust/