# Is all the query in Entity framework 6 is already compiled?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, compiled-query

I want to optimized my queries in **Entity Framework 6.1.3**, so I need to know that whether queries are already CompiledQueries or I need to write them manually as CompiledQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are compiled queries?

Comment: Say what?! You must referring to cached execution but that is up to the database engine.

Comment: The CompiledQuery class provides compilation and caching of queries for reuse.
for more details you can visit this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191721/entity-framework-6-compiled-linq-query

Answer (score 5):

No, they are not. You'll need to specify that you want to use a CompiledQuery.

That said, using a compiled query will only provide a 7% performance improvement. If tuning performance of EF really is a major issue for you, I recommend reading the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853