# How to precompile sql queries in EF Code-First?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am using **ASP.Net4.5.1 & EF6.0** Code-First approach.

I realised that queries are taking considerable time to execute. I have used EF Profiler to check the queries & fine-tuned the queries.

I googled & came to know Compiling Linq.

These are the links I got.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175040/how-to-cache-queries-in-ef-code-first
- [How do I precompile an Entity Framework Code-First Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426508/how-do-i-precompile-an-entity-framework-code-first-query)
- [Entity Framework Compiled Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739925/entity-framework-compiled-query)

But none of them that address my concern.

Suppose I have below query.

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
{
  using(DbContext db = new DbContext()
  {
  IQueryable<Student> query = (from c in db.Students
                                where c.Hobby== "Hockey"
                                select c);
  IEnumerable<Student> students= query.toList<Student>();

  return students;
  }
 }
```

Now how do I cache the query plan or compile this Linq to increase the performance?

One more thing to ask here, is EF slower than native SQL?

I prefer to use EF/ORM, is it right choice?

Comment: are we talking of first query excecution (wich often include view generation time), or query execution in general ?

Comment: @tschmit007
query execution

Comment: Is this code from your app or sample code unrelated to your app?  Based on some of your replies, it seems like you have not posted real code.  It's hard to help if that is the case.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, EF is slower than SQL. This is true of *any* ORM. An ORM must work to transform your code-based "query" into a real SQL query and then it must use the result to instantiate an object graph. However, those are generally things you *want* an ORM for. Doing this type of stuff manually would be more difficult and more error-prone.

Whether you utilize an ORM is entirely dependent on the needs of your application. Generally, yes, an ORM would be recommended, but if you need extreme performance, it might be necessary to drop into pure SQL. ORMs also varied wildly in their individual performance. EF is known to be a particularly slow ORM. It's among the easiest to use and work with, but if performance is a concern, you're better off with something like Dapper. You can also mix and match ORM and SQL usage. It's not abnormal at all to use EF for standard CRUD and then utilize stored procedures for complex queries.

All that said, the query you have is extremely basic. If you're experiencing performance problems with something like that, either your SQL Server instance is not being given enough resources to work with, your network is incredibly slow, or there's a ton of data in that table and you're not utilizing indexes properly.

On that last point, text searches, in general, are among the slowest to perform with SQL. If there's a particular text-based column that you intend to query, such as `Hobby`, then you should add an index on it. You can either do this manually at the database, or utilize the `[Index]` data annotation on the property. Just bear in mind that only fixed-length text-based columns can be indexed. By default, EF will generate string properties as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. If you want to employ indexing on the column, you'll need to combine `[Index]` with `[MaxLength(N)]`.

Comment: thanks.. :) 
I have added proper Unique Index.. can you please suggest me one thing here.. my application is about online booking what you say should I use EF or native SQL

Comment: It's about more than the basic purpose of your application. What kind of load are you expecting? Will it be utilized by hundreds, thousands or millions of people? How complex are the queries you're running? There's a million other questions that could be asked. I'm not expecting actual answers; I'm just saying, *you* have to make the determination. Also, staight SQL should be considered a last resort. Before you go that route, you should be throwing ungodly amounts of RAM and processing cores at both your database and web servers.

Comment: 1k-2.5k Hit per day..
Queries are NOT too complex..now as per you what should I use EF or native SQL

Comment: No, not really, but you're asking all the wrong questions, and more importantly, you're *prematurely optimizing*. Build your application and don't worry about it. When it comes time to deploy, stage it and throw load at, then and only then, optimize as necessary. It's impossible to build an app that will perform perfectly out of the gate. Every situation is unique and optimization and scale is always on the fly. You start with a good base, and then go from there. That's just how this stuff works.

Answer (score 3):

If you want faster data access code, You should consider using Pure ADO.NET code which executes your SQL queries using a `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`'s `ExecuteReader` method. But now you need to write some extra code to create a `SqlCommand`, pass the query and parameters and read the rows from the `SqlDataReader`.

You should consider some mini ORM's like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). It is way faster than EF. You do not need to write much code as I mentioned above. Dapper will execute your queries and map the result set to your DTOs.

Quick example of using Dapper.

```
var con= new SqlConnection("YourConnectionStringGoesHere");
var posts = con.Query<Post>("SELECT ID,Name from Post");
```

Dapper supports reading data from multiple tables (JOIN) and mapping to an object with Navigation properties.

Take a look at their performance numbers
[image]

EF/NHibernate will help you to do Rapid development as it is easy to talk to the database with their API/methods. But you pay for the performance.

Also the important thing to remember is to optimize your sql query. Even with pure ADO.NET, You can get poor performance if your sql query is not optimized. Adding proper indexes to your table/columns might also help.

I am not entirely sure about your application, But you should read about caching data so that your database won't be hit all the time. that will generally improve your performance.

Comment: @Shyju..many thanks... :) my application is online booking system.. can you please suggest me should I go with EF or native SQL? as we are in very intial stage..I feel this is the right stage to decide on it.. FYI Performance is my first concern

Comment: You can always use a mix of Dapper/Pure ADO.NET with EF. You should be able to determine yourself which part of your project needs the optimal performance.