# Compiled query replacement for .Net 4.0 and EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, compiled-query

I have an `Asp.Net MVC` application built with `.Net 4.0` and `EF6`. To improve performance of the application, I came across various posts and got to know that we must have **compiled queries** to drastically increase the performance of the application.

So I went on searching for `compiled query` and wrote my own as below:

```
public static Func<KEEntities, IQueryable<tblProperty>> GetProperties =
            CompiledQuery.Compile((KEEntities db) => 
            from property in db.tblProperties select property);
```

But that query above gives me an error saying Error **There is no implicit reference conversion from 'KEApplication.Models.EntityModel.KEEntities' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext'.**

Again after going through few posts and especially **[`This`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426508/how-do-i-precompile-an-entity-framework-code-first-query/6731102#6731102)**, by reading the **[`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6731102/2065039)** there, I was disappointed to know that the `compiled queries` wasn't supported in `.Net 4` and `EF6`. I also read that `EF` version > 4 provided automatic compilation of queries, but in my case I am not seeing any improvements, if it happened to. Are there any other possible ways to achieve functionality like `compiled query` for the above configurations?

Comment: Did you really ensure that perfomance hit is caused by not compiled queries? I can hardly believe this might have any serious difference compared to how much the actual database query takes.

Comment: I did not perform a deep check. I just optimized my whole application code with `ReSharper` and the only thing now remaining was Query optimization. Above all, I am taking `LINQPad` tool now to test the queries performance.

Comment: If you cannot compile them - how would you compare compiled vs non-compiled version perfomance? Aside from that I bet that you might better spend your time optimizing queries itself (ensure all indexes are in place, ensure query plans are reasonable etc) :)

Comment: Yea! That is well being done.. :) Only problem is with the getting difference, but before that I need to know how I can check it or how I will get assurance that yes my queries work really fast.. :)

Comment: You might also want to read this article: https://blog.codinghorror.com/compiled-or-bust/

Comment: Yea I've read that prior to this question.. Following few of stuffs.. :) Thanks for the info again.. :)